# Centralized error handling for Resitify

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I'm having trouble getting centralized error handling set up in my restify app. I'd like to trap certain Mongo errors, such as "E11000 duplicate key error" and then map them to a restify ConflictError.

If I just let the error bubble up from my Mongo call in a route, the client gets a 500 error.

I figured I should trap InternalServerError, but the below handler never gets called:

```
app.on('InternalServerError', function (req, res, err, cb) {
    console.log('++++++++++++++++', err);
    return cb(err);
});
```

I thought I could just use the express approach:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next){...
```

But restify handlers don't seem to take an error argument.  I'm stumped after searching all the usual places. It seems my first approach should have just worked.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you. Set up a bunyan logger in your app.js file…

```
var bunyan = require('bunyan');
var log = new bunyan({
    name: 'my_api',
    streams: [
        {
            path: './error.log',
            level: 'warn'
        }
    ],
    serializers: {req: restify.bunyan.serializers.req},
    src: false
});

var server = restify.createServer({
    log: log
});
```

Then in your controller do something like this….

```
var restify = require('restify');

try {
    Model.findAll().then(function(vals){
        res.send(vals);
        next();
    });
}
catch(e) {
    req.log.error({req_id: req.id()}, 'Error attempting find.');
    res.send(409, new restify.ConflictError("Problem executing search."));
    next();
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to avoid is exactly that boiler-plate try...catch in each controller.  You'd think we were writing java!  Thanks anyway.